# Reconnecting to an unclosed Socket connection C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a Listener application which expects a string message for display. I cannot modify this application.
I have to send messages to this listener through my C# client. Both the listener and client are supposed to run on the same PC (local host).

**My Code to Connect:**

```
    public void ConnectAndSendMessage(string MessageToSend)
    {
        string localIP = GetIPAddress();

        try
        {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");
            tcpclnt.Connect(localIP, 2400);

            Socket socket = tcpclnt.Client;
            bool connectionStatus = socket.Connected;

            if (connectionStatus)
            {
                //Send Message
                ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                //string sDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                int SendStatus = socket.Send(asen.GetBytes(MessageToSend + Environment.NewLine));
            }
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            tcpclnt.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**

The client application runs fine and send the messages successfully to the Listener. ***But the problem comes if the client gets crashed (I close the client program)  before executing `tcpclnt.Close();`.*** In this case, if I restart the Client program again then,  I cannot connect to the socket since the application didn’t close the socket in the previous run (crashed run).

How can I reconnect to the listener in this condition?

Comment: You should use a `using` block for the `TcpClient` so it still closes the connection if it gets a chance to, depending on how the application crashes. There's also a problem with the program that you cannot change though - usually servers allow multiple connections and have some means of timing out an abandoned connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one..

```
public void ConnectAndSendMessage(string MessageToSend)
{
    string localIP = GetIPAddress();

    using (System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient tcpclnt = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");
            tcpclnt.Connect(localIP, 2400);

            using (System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket = tcpclnt.Client)
            {
                if (socket.Connected)
                {
                    //Send Message
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding asen = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                    //string sDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                    int SendStatus = socket.Send(asen.GetBytes(MessageToSend + Environment.NewLine));
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (tcpclnt != null && tcpclnt.Connected)
                tcpclnt.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't solve the problem. Its not an exception. If I debug the code then, I see that the line `bool connectionStatus = socket.Connected;` return false but it never enters into the catch block.

Comment: as soon as I put `using` block, the `tcpclnt` goes out of context ini try and catch blocks.

Comment: no its not out of context try block is after first using block

Comment: @skm To make it more better i just put finally block and close the connection within it.

Comment: With that, I got an exception `Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: No bro there is no exception come for me. check again and if exception comes again tell me the line no.

Comment: thanks, it worked. I forgot to comment out `tcpclnt.Close();` from try block thats why I got an exception in the Finally block.